# Flask CORS not working on live deployment

Tags: python-3.x, firebase, heroku, flask, cors

I have been struggling for dozens of hours trying to figure out why is the application producing a CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing) error

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api-client.herokuapp.com/retrieve_email' from origin 'https://front-application.firebaseapp.com' has been blocked by 
CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Although I have added CORS to my backend application and works perfectly on the localhost for testing. Once I deploy both the front end and backend to hosting servers, I get the CORS error. What is more interesting it only applies to the `/retrieve_email` path, but works on the `login` - both paths require CORS though. The `/` path works fine, it displays the `JSON` from it, which I also tested using Postman.

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_cors import CORS
from email_receive import EmailReceive
from email_send import EmailSend


app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

email_test = EmailReceive()


@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    return jsonify({'key': 'value'})


@app.route('/retrieve_email', methods=['GET'])
def retrieve_email():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        email_test.email_receive()
        return jsonify(email_test.get_email_data())


@app.route('/login', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.get_json()
        email_test.set_credentials(data)
        return jsonify(data)
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        return jsonify(email_test.get_email_data())


@app.route('/send_email', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def send_email():
    sending = EmailSend()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.get_json()
        sending.set_information(data)
        sending.email_send()
        return jsonify(data)
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        return jsonify({'key': 'value'})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Above is a snippet of my code using CORS. Please don't laugh at the structure of the code, this is the first time using an API and using GET, and POST requests. Frontend(Angular) is hosted on Firebase, backend(Flask) hosted on Heroku.

EDIT 1: I ran `heroku logs --tail`, basically just looking at some logs through the terminal, the following is what I got:

```
2019-03-14T19:03:35.999761+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-03-14 19:03:35,999] ERROR in app: Exception on /retrieve_email [GET]
2019-03-14T19:03:35.999772+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2019-03-14T19:03:35.999774+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
2019-03-14T19:03:35.999776+00:00 app[web.1]: response = self.full_dispatch_request()
2019-03-14T19:03:35.999778+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
2019-03-14T19:03:35.999779+00:00 app[web.1]: rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
2019-03-14T19:03:35.999780+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 161, in wrapped_function
2019-03-14T19:03:35.999782+00:00 app[web.1]: return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
2019-03-14T19:03:35.999783+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
2019-03-14T19:03:35.999785+00:00 app[web.1]: reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
2019-03-14T19:03:35.999787+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
2019-03-14T19:03:35.999790+00:00 app[web.1]: raise value
2019-03-14T19:03:35.999791+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
2019-03-14T19:03:35.999793+00:00 app[web.1]: rv = self.dispatch_request()
2019-03-14T19:03:35.999794+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
2019-03-14T19:03:35.999796+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
2019-03-14T19:03:35.999798+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: decorator() missing 1 required positional argument: 'f'
2019-03-14T19:03:36.001321+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.45.158.146 - - [14/Mar/2019:19:03:35 +0000] "GET /retrieve_email HTTP/1.1" 500 291 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.6.0"
2019-03-14T19:03:36.063632+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/retrieve_email" host=email-client-live.herokuapp.com request_id=3dd5bc4a-0f57-4a82-b5f7-1bcccc64f263 fwd="73.210.197.125" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=73ms status=500 bytes=488 protocol=https
```

The following is the code for the email_receive() function:

```
import email
import email.header
import imaplib
import sys


class EmailReceive:
    imap_host = ''
    imap_user = ''
    imap_pass = ''

    email_package = []

    def __init__(self):
        self.imap_host = 'imap.gmail.com'
        self.imap_user = 'xxxxxxxx@gmail.com'
        self.imap_pass = 'xxxxxxxxxx'

    def set_credentials(self, data):
        self.imap_user = data['email']
        self.imap_pass = data['password']

    def email_receive(self):
        self.email_package = []
        email_instance = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(self.imap_host)

        try:
            print(self.imap_user, self.imap_pass)
            rv, data = email_instance.login(self.imap_user, self.imap_pass)
        except imaplib.IMAP4.error:
            print('[*] email_receive.py: LOGIN FAILED')
            sys.exit(1)

        print(rv, data)

        rv, data = email_instance.list()
        if rv == 'OK':
            print('Mailboxes: ')
            print(data)

        rv, data = email_instance.select('Inbox')
        if rv == 'OK':
            print('Processing mailbox...')
            print(data)

        rv, data = email_instance.search(None, 'ALL')
        if rv != 'OK':
            print('[*] email_receive.py: No messages found!')
            return

        for num in data[0].split():
            rv, data = email_instance.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
            if rv != 'OK':
                # print('[*] email_receive.py: ERROR getting message', num)
                return

            # print(data[0][1])

            message = email.message_from_bytes(data[0][1])
            subject = email.header.make_header(email.header.decode_header(message['Subject']))
            # print(message.keys())
            message_id = message['Message-ID']

            # print(header)
            sender = message['From']

            for part in message.walk():
                if part.get_content_type() == 'text/html':
                    self.email_package.append({'body': part.get_payload(decode=True).decode('utf-8'),
                                               'subject': str(subject),
                                               'from': str(sender),
                                               'messageid': str(message_id)})

    def get_email_data(self):
        return self.email_package
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
from flask_cors import cross_origin
```

then add @cross_origin() decorator to your api route like this

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
@cross_origin()
def index():
    ...
```

Comment: HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 500, statusText: "INTERNAL SERVER ERROR", url: "https://email-client-live.herokuapp.com/retrieve_email", ok: false, …}

I am assuming that there is a problem with the hosting server, Heroku, because going to https://api-client.herokuapp.com/ gives back the json, but https://api-client.herokuapp.com/retrieve_email gives the error mentioned above. I am trying to retrieve emails from gmail using IMAP, so I am wondering if credential verification (login information is the problem).

Comment: I also tried accessing the api-client.herokuapp.com/retrieve_email URL through the development environment, it produce the same error. Although api-client.herokuapp.com/login works fine on both live and development environments.

Comment: Tbh, I think the @cross_origin decorator is causing more problems. By changing the return for /retrieve_email route to jsonify({'key': 'value'}) doesn't work anymore(I tested it with Postman). Removing the decorator clears out he problem.

Comment: @ElonasMarcauskas, error 500 is something wrong inside your codes, you got a interval error, then it throws error 500.So I suggest you check this email_test.email_receive() method 1st(one of the reason may causes this error is Gmail blocks your server as the third party access for security reason). As for the decorator,I am using this decorator for my project and so far I haven't got any errors for that.For jsonify ,it just a method that convert you response to json format(like json.dumps) but  with appropriate content-type header 'application/json' for use with json responses.

Comment: Okay I will look at the code, I will post it once I get the chance. I have been having issues with Gmail blocking my connection and retrieving emails.

Comment: I posted the code for the email_receive() method. I am wondering if print statements could cause errors on the hosting server when they are executed. Also, this could be an issue with Gmail security, because I did receive emails that someone is trying to access the application from a "weird" location. Although, I did "Allow less secure app" option on Gmail, which according to my research could prevent logging in.

Comment: @ElonasMarcauskas sorry, i missed () for the cross_origin decorator....it should be cross_origin()..try it one more time, sorry about this, I changed the answer already

Comment: Sorry, I wrote it with the brackets in my application, such as @cross_origin(). I will try it one more time. But I am coming to the conclusion it is a problem with google security. I keep receiving emails that the connection has been denied from the remote backend server.